# Embedded R Try Except Add Loop

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm following along with the blog below as a python/R novice and having trouble adding a loop statement to the code below. Currently i'm able to get the code run in full, but only outputs the seasonal flag for 1 customer. I would like it to loop and run for all of my customers.

[datamovesme.com/2018/07/01/seasonality-python-code](https://datamovesme.com/2018/07/01/seasonality-python-code/)

```
##Here comes the R code piece     
     try:
          seasonal = r(''' 
          fit<-tbats(customerTS, seasonal.periods = 12, use.parallel = TRUE)
          fit$seasonal
          ''')
      except: seasonal = 1
      seasonal_output = seasonal_output.append({'customer_id':customerid, 'seasonal': seasonal}, ignore_index=True)
      print(f' {customerid} | {seasonal} ')
print(seasonal_output)
seasonal_output.to_csv(outfile)
```

I've tried many combinations of code to get it to loop, too many to list here. The blog shows the existing data frames, and time-series objects that are available to us. I am not sure which one to use and how to pass it to the R code.

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry about that, I have fixed indentation. Oh, this is already running for all Customer_id? I actually have proper indentation (if my edit is correct) in the actual code that's been running, but I always just get 1 row output. I see the for loop but didn't realize that applied to the R code section. Is the issue that I'm running it step by step and not as 1 big script?

Comment: Did you incorporate the `for` ... `groupby` line? Which runs across all customerid?

Comment: I have this line: "for customerid, dataForCustomer in filledIn.groupby(by=['customer_id']):" but I am running it step by step. I am now noticing the indentation, the TRY is part of the loop it looks like? and I just need to run the entire script instead of 1 step at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog link maintains issues:

1. Code does not properly indent lines as a requirement in Python syntax. Possibly, this is due to website rendering of white space or tabs but this is a disservice to readers as missing an indent changes output.
2. Code failed to heed the inefficiency issue of appending data frames: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451). Instead, since *seasonal* is one value build a list of dictionaries that you cast into the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor outside of the loop.

After resolving above issues and running entire code block, your solution should output a data frame across all *customerids*.

```
# ... same above assignments ...
outfile = '[put your file path here].csv'
df_list = []

for customerid, dataForCustomer in filledIn.groupby(by=['customer_id']):
    startYear = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].yr
    startMonth = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].mnth
    endYear = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].yr
    endMonth = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].mnth

    #Creating a time series object
    customerTS = stats.ts(dataForCustomer.usage.astype(int),
                          start=base.c(startYear,startMonth),
                          end=base.c(endYear, endMonth), 
                          frequency=12)
    r.assign('customerTS', customerTS)

    ##Here comes the R code piece
    try:
        seasonal = r('''
                        fit<-tbats(customerTS, seasonal.periods = 12, use.parallel = TRUE)
                        fit$seasonal
                     ''')
    except: 
        seasonal = 1

    # APPEND DICTIONARY TO LIST (NOT DATA FRAME)
    df_list.append({'customer_id': customerid, 'seasonal': seasonal})
    print(f' {customerid} | {seasonal} ')

seasonal_output = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
print(seasonal_output)
seasonal_output.to_csv(outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Parfait !! I actually did find a different version of the blog that had proper indentation: https://www.kristenkehrer.com/seasonality-code

Comment: I'm sure this is correct but I will try tonight to see if i can get it working. It makes a lot of sense that I missed the nesting within the original for loop. And thank you for the dictionary suggestion!!!!

Comment: But still appends data frame in a loop. If you have many customers, your poor machine will wrestle with heavy quadratic copying!

Comment: thank you @parfait- using your code / adjusting the indentation got the code to run for all customers. I sent 2,000 customers through that all have 2 years worth of monthly sales data (including 0 months), but got 0 customers flagged as seasonal, so I think there's still an issue somewhere.

Comment: Where does this object `dataForOwner.SENDS` derive as used in `stats.ts()` call? In fact, Python should have raised an `NameError` here. Should it be `dataForCustomer.usage`?

Comment: yes exactly @Parfait, i had to fix by swapping in     dataforCustomer.usage

Comment: Does that solve seasonal issue? And are customer values all 0's or 1's?

Comment: No, it did not solve the issue. I had fixed that, then was able to get it to run for the 2000 customers. The values are all actually NULL, not 0 or 1. Should I submit a new help request?

Comment: I did submit a new request, to close out this question. This is the link if you are able to take a look. Thank you for all your help ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954983/r-tbats-model-seasonal-customer-flag-no-results