# R tbats Model Seasonal Customer Flag No Results

Tags: python, r, time-series, rpy2

I am following this blog to identify seasonal customers in my time series data: 
https://www.kristenkehrer.com/seasonality-code

My code is shamelessly nearly identical to the blog, with some small tweaks, code is below. I am able to run the code entirely, for 2000 customers. A few hours later, 0 customers were flagged as seasonal in my results.

Manually looking at customers data over time, I do believe I have many examples of seasonal customers that should have been picked up. Below is a sample of the data I am using.

Am I missing something stupid? am I in way over my head to even try this, being very new to python?

Note that I am adding the "0 months" in my data source, but I don't think it would hurt anything for that function to check again. I'm also not including the data source credentials step.

Thank you

[image: Sample Data]

```
import pandas as pa
import numpy as np
import pyodbc as py

cnxn = py.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

original = pa.read_sql_query('SELECT s.customer_id, s.yr, s.mnth, Case when s.usage<0 then 0 else s.usage end as usage  FROM dbo.Seasonal  s   Join   ( Select Top 2000  customer_id, SUM(usage) as usage   From dbo.Seasonal where Yr!=2018    Group by customer_id ) t ON s.customer_id = t.customer_id Where yr!= 2018 Order by customer_id, yr, mnth', cnxn)

grouped = original.groupby(by='customer_id')

def yearmonth_to_justmonth(year, month):

    return year * 12 + month - 1

def fillInForOwner(group):
    min = group.head(1).iloc[0]
    max = group.tail(1).iloc[0]
    minMonths = yearmonth_to_justmonth(min.yr, min.mnth)
    maxMonths = yearmonth_to_justmonth(max.yr, max.mnth)
    filled_index = pa.Index(np.arange(minMonths, maxMonths, 1), name="filled_months")
    group['months'] = group.yr * 12 + group.mnth - 1
    group = group.set_index('months')
    group = group.reindex(filled_index)
    group.customer_id = min.customer_id
    group.yr = group.index // 12
    group.mnth = group.index % 12 + 1
    group.usage = np.where(group.usage.isnull(), 0, group.usage).astype(int)
    return group

filledIn = grouped.apply(fillInForOwner)
newIndex = pa.Index(np.arange(filledIn.customer_id.count()))

import rpy2 as r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri, globalenv
pandas2ri.activate()

base = importr('base')
colorspace = importr('colorspace')
forecast = importr('forecast')
times = importr('timeSeries')
stats = importr('stats')

outfile = 'results.csv'
df_list = []

for customerid, dataForCustomer in filledIn.groupby(by=['customer_id']):
    startYear = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].yr
    startMonth = dataForCustomer.head(1).iloc[0].mnth
    endYear = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].yr
    endMonth = dataForCustomer.tail(1).iloc[0].mnth


    customerTS = stats.ts(dataForCustomer.usage.astype(int),
                      start=base.c(startYear,startMonth),
                      end=base.c(endYear, endMonth), 
                      frequency=12)
    r.assign('customerTS', customerTS)

    try:
        seasonal = r('''
                        fit<-tbats(customerTS, seasonal.periods = 12, 
                        use.parallel = TRUE)
                        fit$seasonal
                     ''')
    except: 
        seasonal = 1
    df_list.append({'customer_id': customerid, 'seasonal': seasonal})
    print(f' {customerid} | {seasonal} ')

seasonal_output = pa.DataFrame(df_list)
print(seasonal_output)
seasonal_output.to_csv(outfile)
```

Comment: Does code work fully in R? To check, please export *filledIn* dataset to csv and run the [R script version here](https://pastebin.com/JZfjheXh)

Comment: I will try that tonight @parfait, thank you!

Comment: @Parfait I got the following error when running the code in R after importing the CSV. "Error in names(IND) <- deparse(substitute(INDICES))[1L]: 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Traceback:"

Comment: Check that all variables names are properly spelled including case sensitivity. Above uses *customerid* but it may need to have underscore: *customer_id*.

Comment: @parfait i fixed the customer_id and it ran! Unfortunately the output for all 50 of my test accounts was Seasonal=1. I am guessing 1 means yes so it thinks they are all seasonal which can't be correct. I noticed my original data set does have 24 rows for each customer, 2 12 month periods. The "filledIn" data set only has 23 rows for each customer, all are missing the 2nd years 12th month. I'm not sure if that's intentional, or could be the issue and the reason why i'm not getting accurate results.

Comment: Since `seasonal = 1` is wrapped in a `tryCatch` (similar to Python's `try/except`) it is the value assigned upon error. So your `tbats()` call is raising an error. Since an R error is not a Python error, the `except` block was never run and so *seasonal* returned `NULL`. Not knowing the model, I cannot tell from data alone why it would err. Consider testing in a non-loop simulation (i.e., pick one customer) and see the full, raised error message.

Comment: thanks @parfait. I see how that is working now. I think i'm a little over my head with trying to update the code to run without the loop/adding the error message/troubleshooting the tbats model error, but that suggestion makes sense. I will have to dig into further.

Comment: In error block of `tryCatch`, force error to be raised with `error = function(e) { print(paste("MY_ERROR:  ", e));  return(1)})`

Comment: thank you @parfait as always! I did finally get results! The value "12" for all 50 of the test customers. I'm not sure what that means so I need to keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

Kristen here (that's my code).  1 actually means that the customers are not seasonal (or it couldn't pick it up) and NULL also means not seasonal.  If they have a seasonal usage pattern (period of 12 months, which is what the code is looking for) it'll output [12].

You can always confirm by inspecting a graph of a single customers behavior and then putting it through the algorithm.  I also liked to cross check with a seasonal decomposition algo in either Python or R.

Here is some R code for looking at the decomposition of your time series.  If there is no seasonal window in the plot your results are not seasonal:

```
library(forecast)
myts<-ts(mydata$SENDS, start=c(2013,1),end=c(2018,2),frequency = 12)
plot(decompose(myts))
```

Also, you mentioned having problems with some of the 0's not filling in (from your twitter conversation)  I haven't had this problem but my customers have varying lengths of tenure from 2 years to 13 years. Not sure what the problem is here.

Let me know if I can help with anything else :)

Comment: Thank you @Krissy K ! I was getting all 1's, now i'm actually getting all 12's, just having trouble getting a mix! thank you for the troubleshooting code, i will take a look at that.

Comment: The 0's not filling in part was.. for a customer, my original data set has 24 rows for years of data by month, some with 0s some without. After it goes through the fillInForOwner function, the "filledIn" dataset only has 23 rows for that same customer. So I wasn't sure if I have an issue in that spot. I thought it was odd that the dataset passed to the R isn't including that last month.

Answer (score 0):

Circling back to answer how I got this to work was by just passing the "original" dataframe into the for loop. My data already had the empty $0 months so I didn't need that part of the code to run. Thank you all for your help